ADF Monitor interface - run start and run end
What timezone is used in ADF Monitor for [Run start] and [Run end], is it UTC by default?
I did not find any info in the doc page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/monitor-visually
Thanks for any hint!

The timezone for ADF pipeline monitor is not UTC by default. I had different timezone in my ADF pipeline. To check the current timezone and change the timezone, follow the below step,

Click the monitor icon in ADF.
Click the time Range, time zone icon
Check the current timezone from the timezone box.
Change the timezone if required.


